# Want to create virtual env 3.7 ( Fedora 36 Linux )

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, devops, fedora

I have python 3.10 something installed in my system
Used both the commands :
**virtualenv -p python3.7 env,
virtualenv --python python3.7 venv**

RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.7'

But it is showing me this error , I have everything installed in my system

Answer (score 1):

According to [fedora developer](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/python/multiple-pythons.html), you can install python 3.7 with

```
sudo dnf install python3.7
```

Comment: But i want to create virtual environment , so why should i download it

Comment: @Anurag: The `venv` command does not download Python versions for u.